# How do I use the record button in AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, script

I don't understand how the Record system works in AppleScript.  [The instructions](https://support.apple.com/guide/script-editor/record-actions-scpedt1009/mac) seem clear, but not very helpful.

> 1. In the Script Editor app / on your Mac, click the Record button ⏺ in the toolbar.
> 2. Perform the actions you want to record in the recordable app.
> 3. To stop recording, click the Stop button ⏹

Seems easy enough. So I do that..

- Open up Script Editor on MacOS, start a new script (File --> New).
- Hit the red record button.
- Open up my messages app. Enter my own phone number, enter a message "test" then send.
- Hit the Stop button in the Script Editor.

Great, but where is the recorded script?  It didn't go to the empty script.  Its not stored in the clipboard (Command-v = blank)

Am I doing this correctly?  Where is the recorded content?

*MacOS = Big Sur (11.0.1)

Script Editor= 2.11 (225) AppleScript 2.7

Scripting language = AppleScript*

Comment: I believe that the script will populate with commands that it can actually record. If no commands are populated in the script window, then you didn't do something that Script Editor could record (I may be way off on that, I haven't tried the record button in a long long time). That being said, most people don't use that record button. You'd be better off trying Automator, or getting a utility like Keyboard Maestro that has a recording function that works better, ymmv.

Comment: I'm actually trying to troubleshoot a message script that broke with BigSur update.  I was trying to create a new simple script to see if there were any formatting differences.  Are you saying that Messages is scriptable but not recordable?  Can you confirm that on your MacOS?

Comment: Very few applications are “recordable”.  Messages is not one of them.  Finder is one of those recordable applications.

Comment: Am I unreasonable to expect a "Beware, some applications are not recordable" popup upon a stop command with empty buffer?  ... sigh.  @ChrisNorman  If you summarize your stuff as an answer, and confirm that Messages in not recordable, I'll accept it.. many thx to all.

Comment: @zipzit I am confirming that Messages.app is not recordable.  Can you edit your post to include the code that is giving you the problem? This will allow others to be able to help you

Comment: One question at a time.  Keep it simple.  The code in I'm actually working on [is here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61356595/applescript-message-format-total-fail-on-new-line-feed) Lets leave this question simple so others don't waste time on the whole record button fail.. ever.

Comment: Without looking at the code, I felt that I should mention that Messages in Big Sur is a Catalyst App (https://developer.apple.com/mac-catalyst/) so I think that pretty much blew away any scripting you could do for messages. I might be wrong (again), but I have not heard of Catalyst app's being scriptable.

Comment: @ChrisNorman Interesting.  Sounds like the fix for my dilemma of sending out nicely formatted SMS/text page to a long list of individual recipients may be better served via Xcode than Script Editor.  I hadn't previously considered that direction.  How do you guys send out text pages to 120 people at a time (hint, group texts are WAY BAD)?

Comment: @zipzit maybe look for an SMS client for the Mac?

Comment: Apple Script issues resolved at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65028482). Send out nicely formatted text page to 125 individual phone numbers. Done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, the Message system is not recordable in MacOS AppleScript Editor.

- There is no error message, or any other feedback.  It's just a fail.
- Comments from others: *That being said, most people don't use that record button. You'd be better off trying Automator, or getting a utility like Keyboard Maestro that has a recording function that works better.* - ChrisNorman
- *Very few applications are “recordable”. Messages is not one of them. Finder is one of those recordable applications.* – wch1zpink

Comment: I can't get mail.app to record anything either.  Trying to create an automator service to move a selected message into a mailbox On My Mac.  Automator can't do it; says use apple script.  AppleScript has the commands, but sure wish I could record a script to get a prototype to follow.  Oh well.  Apple seems to be letting more and more stuff just get stale.  They're learning from google I guess.

Comment: We share your pain.   I will say, Google has a pretty good bug user submit and tracking system, with complete visibility.